# Play Framework (Java): Adding fields to Form Object at Runtime

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.0

I have a HTML-form on a template with a form object (name it x) based on a model. On the same HTML-form there is one field (name it y) belonging to another model (z) because for users it is convenient to submit that information together.

Is is possible to add field y to form x on runtime? It's easy to add one extra text-field to HTML-form on template, but since it's from another model it can't be evaluated with x.hasErrors() and it doesn't get "This field is required" -label on badRequest call.

It there other good ways to do this? Should I send two form objects (x and z) to the template? In my case it seems not to work, since both x and z has field of same name.